# Is Content Security Policy forward compatible?

Tags: content-security-policy

If `script-src: hash-source` is used in a browser that does not understand `hash-source`, will the browser ignore all of `script-src:`, or even all of the CSP? Or will it only ignore the `hash-source` part?

More generally, do browsers implement CSP in forward compatible manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What oreoshake stated about backward compatibility is accurate. The process of determining an element match is described in [section 6.6.2.2 of the CSP draft standard](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#allow-all-inline): In the presence of `hash-source` or `nonce-source`, `unsafe-inline` is ignored by conforming user agents:

> A source list allows all inline behavior of a given type if it contains the keyword-source expression 'unsafe-inline', and does not override that expression as described in the following algorithm:
>
> [...]
>
> If expression matches the nonce-source or hash-source grammar, return "Does Not Allow".

Furthermore, CSP 2 specifies the process of [parsing a source list with unknown tokens](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#source-list-parsing) as follows:

> For each token returned by splitting source list on spaces, if the token matches the grammar for source-expression, add the token to the set of source expressions.

Otherwise, it should be ignored. So clearly the authors intended at least a certain  level of forward compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers that do not understand hash source elements may emit a warning in the console, but they may not as well. The recommended approach is to use user agent sniffing to detect support or send both `'unsafe-inline'` with your hash source values.

User agents that understand hash sources will ignore the `'unsafe-inline'` and those that do not will fallback to the `'unsafe-inline'`. So it's *backwards* compatible.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm aware of the fact that CSP is backwards compatible, but I'm wondering if it's also forward compatible or if using directives unknown to a browser break the CSP rules entirely for that browser.

Comment: This does answer your question. Browsers that don’t understand nonces still apply the CSP they DO understand, even in the presence of nonces